# How to make a Webservice request follow a redirect?

Tags: java, redirect, web-services, http-status-code-302

My application neeeds to access a third part web service. 
Of late, they have introduced a load balancer, which redirects to the server. 
Because of this the webservice gets a 302 - Redirect error as response.

In the SOAPUI, I was able to enable a property called "Follow Redirect", and because of this service followed the redirect and served by the server.

Now is there a similar propety that can be turned on in the code, which would make the webservice follow the request?

(The calling code is java and the webservice is in .net)

Comment: You need to say 'what code' you're referring to, since any library is likely to be configured differently.

Comment: I use Jboss provided service library and used jaxws to generate the stubs. ????

Comment: Had the same problem - please check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145096/java-web-service-client-generated-in-netbeans-getting-http-status-code-307/9763571#9763571

Comment: Generally speaking, the load balancer is configured improperly. It should not parse HTTP requests, but should rather balance TCP connections. Or a DNS round-robin should be involved. It's a bad idea and poor design to do HTTP redirects. You should probably open a support ticket on that 3rd party web service.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be supported by the library implementing the actual call to the web service, and there is not a generic way of setting this.

Comment: I am new to webservices...so not really sure what you are reffering to by the 'what code' - library, 
I am using jboss services class..and generated the stubs using jaxws....does this information help, to me help me out???