# Webservice Follow Redirect False - Error 302 (JAXWS)

Tags: redirect, web-services, jax-ws, http-status-code-302

This is a link to a question I had asked two days back,

[How to make a Webservice request follow a redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573858/how-to-make-a-webservice-request-follow-a-redirect)

I am using jaxws library.

The service forms the URL, and then internally creates the HTTPURLConnection. If I can grab hold of the connection I would be able to set the followRedirect to true.

But not getting a handle of the same. Its urgent, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a handle of HttpUrlConnection.setforwardRedirect(true)

Comment: Correct, but according to the Javadoc it already defaults to `true` so there should be no need to call this method.

Answer (score 5):

You can set

```
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, _url);
```

where url is the real URl (after redirection).

Comment: worked perfect for me. My problem was a jax-ws client talking to an axis server.