# ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 302: Found

Tags: java, soap, webservice-client

I am testing a webservice and it works fine in SOAP UI tool.
Now I am writing a webservice client in java to test same. I executed the wsimport command  and generated the required classes. 
The issue is when I am calling the service it displays the following message in console. It seems the server is trying to redirect but redirection is failing. I am doubting there may be issue with http/https OR GET/POST methods but not sure how to fix.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 302: Found
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Please suggest.

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 3):

After more analysis and change I am able to fix this issue. As I doubted the cause was redirection from http to https.
This post helped: [Calling web service that sits on a load balancer with jax-ws returns at http status of 302, but when I use SoapUI it works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702022/calling-web-service-that-sits-on-a-load-balancer-with-jax-ws-returns-at-http-sta)

Regards,
Arun